# No GPU memory when inferencing with Tensorflow

Tags: amazon-ec2, tensorflow

I'm inferencing one image on a just-started EC2 instance (G2) with Tensorflow. But saw the following error:

[image]

I'm not sure if it's a GPU or Tensorflow setup issue because the instance has been stopped for a while and I just started it. The memory shouldn't be a problem. Please help me diagnose it. Thanks!